# CreateEmptyPrefab does not keep texture on meshRenderer

Tags: unity-game-engine, instantiation, texture2d, gameobject

I'm creating a prefab dynamically and trying to set a bunch of properties on a child GameObject. One of those properties is a texture, and though the texture does appear as a child of the prefab (in the same way the GameObject and Mesh do), the MeshRenderer on the GameObject still shows no material and the whole mesh shows up pink. Here's my code:

```
Texture2D sharedTexture = (Texture2D)Resources.Load ("mainTexture", typeof(Texture2D));

string prefabPath = basepath + filename + ".prefab";
UnityEngine.Object prefab = PrefabUtility.CreateEmptyPrefab (prefabPath);
GameObject root = new GameObject ("Zone_" + filename);

GameObject temp = new GameObject(filename);
Texture2D texCopy = (Texture2D)UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate (sharedTexture);
MeshFilter meshFilter = (MeshFilter)temp.AddComponent<MeshFilter> ();
MeshRenderer meshRenderer = temp.AddComponent<MeshRenderer> ();
MeshCollider meshCollider = (MeshCollider)temp.AddComponent<MeshCollider> ();
temp.AddComponent<Zone> ();
Mesh mesh = buildMeshForFilename (filename);
mesh.name = "Zone_Mesh";
meshFilter.mesh = mesh;
meshCollider.sharedMesh = mesh;
meshRenderer.material.mainTexture = texCopy;
temp.transform.parent = root.transform;
AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset(mesh, prefabPath);
AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset (texCopy, prefabPath);


PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab(root, prefab, ReplacePrefabOptions.ConnectToPrefab);
AssetDatabase.SaveAssets ();
GameObject.Destroy (root);
```

How do I get the texture to show on the mesh, so it's not just pink?

Comment: Objects showing up pink is more often a shader issue. Check what shader is assigned to you prefabs and if it is correct on the instantiated ones.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, solved it. For future reference of anyone stumbling upon this, I fixed it by doing the following things:

I removed references to the Texture2D (both sharedTexture and texCopy). Then I dragged my png onto a game object in the editor which generated a Material and dropped it into a Materials folder that it created. I then load that Material using the AssetDatabase, like so:

```
Material mainMat = (Material)AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath ("Assets/resources/Materials/mainTexture.mat", typeof(Material));
```

I then assign that material directly to the MeshRenderer like so:

```
meshRenderer.material = mainMat;
```

That seemed to be enough.